# Best practices to create a Twig HTML Layout (Masterpage)

Tags: php, html, twig

I have been developing `C#/ASP.net` MVC-App for 5 years and I am now learning `PHP`.

In `C#`, I can use `RenderBody` for each new site, so the new HTML content will be replaced in `RenderBody()`. Then, I have only one new partial view and one new controller for each site:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>RenderBody()</body>
</html>
```

When using Twig, I have a skeleton Layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>{%block ablock%}{%endblock%}</body>
</html>
```

For every new site, I need to make a new `child.twig` file and extend the main layout, then override the 'ablock'. By doing it this way, I still need a PHP file (let's call them `index1.php`, `index2.php`, etc) which calls the twig load functions with the `child.twig` as a parameter. In the end, I have to create 2 views (the `child.twig` + `index.php`) and one more php file for the controller. So my question is :

**What is the best way to create an HTML-Masterpage in MVC with Twig?**

I could not find any public project / tutorial mentioning the best practices to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at [knpUniversities](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/twig) tutorial on twig (this one is free). Everything you need should be in there.

Comment: thx i will take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always create a general template with the content that share all pages:

> generalTemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
    <meta name="Author">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{project_path}}resources/images/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Here put the general CSS and JS -->
    {% block head %} {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then creates the children who inherit general template:

> oneChild.html

```
{% extends "generalTemplate.html" %}

{% block head %}
<!-- Specific libraries css and js -->
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Specific HTML content -->
{% endblock %}
```

> index.php

```
require_once 'Twig/Autoloader.php'; 

Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(path_to_generalTemplatehtml);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array());

$template = $twig->loadTemplate($path_to_oneChildhtml);

$data = array();
$data['project_title'] = $project_title;
$data['project_path'] = $project_path;

echo $template->render($data);
```

Anyway, there is a fine documentation on Twig with great detail: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Comment: Thx miguel. But u still need to call the oneChild.html in an extra php file right? So in a index.php: $template->display() / echo twig.render(). But i want only one page for one new view lets say oneChild.html.

Comment: No. In your .php you put that I write in the response.