# Include one and the same html on many pages

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design, include

I have this html text on many pages

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Account</title>
<link href="css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 450px)' href='css/narrow.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 800)' href='css/medium.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 801px)' href='css/wide.css' />
</head>
```

The problem is that I want to use this same code for many pages without having to copy and paste over let's say 5 pages. Is there a clever way to use an "include" command for this?

Comment: You would just use an ordinary `include()`, nothing clever. You can also use `include_once()` to be really clean. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php I might add that unless the `<title>` tags always have the same value, perhaps give the included file a .php extension and drive the title through a variable or constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a file with this:

> File with libs

```
 <meta charset='utf-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>
 <title>Account</title>
 <link href='css/Master.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 450px)' href='css/narrow.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 800)' href='css/medium.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 801px)' href='css/wide.css' />
```

> HTML

```
<head>
  <?php include("file_with_libs.php"); ?>
</head>
```

But I advise you that use a template engine like Twig. You have all information in: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Or You can see other reply that i wrote, explaining how to use Twig: [Best practices to create a Twig HTML Layout (Masterpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327421/best-practices-to-create-a-twig-html-layout-masterpage/36327711#36327711)

Comment: The HTML content doesn't contain any PHP fragment, so you can avoid using `<?php echo...` and put directly the HTML.

Comment: `echo` is not needed.

Comment: it is true, thanks to you both, and I changed

Comment: And also the "; at the very end of  <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 801px)' href='css/wide.css' />"; is not needed either :)

Comment: @user5095266 Opss, let carelessness! I changed this now

Answer (score 3):

If you are using php you can make a new file page-element.php and paste your content in that file.

Then in every page where you want to use this element you can use

```
<?php
include_once "page-element.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your server is configured to use server side includes. That may be an easy way to achieve what you want without needing PHP.

I am making a bit of an assumption that you are using Apache, which I accept may be incorrect but IIS and Ngnix both provide SSI functionality, though I am not sure how similar they are to Apache's.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html